# Decompiling APK but missing some classes?

Tags: android, decompiling

[image]

After decompile APK，I want to find the method `com.welove520.welove.l.e.a(String, String, Map)`.

But the match package path does not have Class `e`.

`smali` have the same phenomenon. But `java -jar apktool.jar b **` still normal.

How to solve the problem?

What would causes this situation?

Comment: yes decompling apk is not that much easy, there so many things are missing

Comment: Ask question related to problem. Missing file questions are off topic.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem.

The decompiled apk has 2 `dex`:`classes.dex` `classes2.dex`, the missing classes are in the second `classes2.dex`.